# Oribt controls not working, mouse cant move scene

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've been trying to figure this one out for a bit and I'm not sure if it's something to do with the OrbitControls.js or my code. I'm trying to simply get orbit controls to work but nothing seems to move.

I used:

```
    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, scene);
```

instead of renderer.domElement as when I use that I can no longer see my scene.

If anyone has any suggestions it would be much appreciated.

here's my code:

```
        <script src="libraries/three.min.js"></script>
        <script src="libraries/OrbitControls.js"></script>
        


        <script>


            let scene,camera,renderer, controls;

            function init(){

                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xdddddd );
//Camera Things

                        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/  window.innerHeight, 0.1, 5000 );
                        camera.position.set(0,25,25);

//cube
                        var cubeGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry (10,10,10);
                        var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial ({color: 0x1ec876});
                        cube = new THREE.Mesh (cubeGeometry, cubeMaterial);

                        cube.position.set (0, 0, 0);
                        scene.add (cube);

// controls
                    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, scene);

                    scene.add( new THREE.AxesHelper(500));

// Renderer
                    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);
                    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
                    animate();
                    }

                function animate() {
                controls.update();
                renderer.render( scene, camera );
                requestAnimationFrame( animate );
                }

                init();


        </script>
    </body>
```

Thankyou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, scene);

You always have to pass in a DOM element as the second argument. Not a 3D object or scene. So the correct code is:

```js
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
```

Of course this code needs to be executed *after* the renderer has been created.